# hamiltonian cycle v^2 algorithm?

Tags: graph-algorithm, hamiltonian-cycle

Is there a algorithm that will find as long as possible hamiltonian cycles in v^2 time. I am running a program that needs to find cycles on a sparse graph (4v edges at maximum), and according to my calculations, I need v^2 or better. I understand that to operate in v^2 it would have to be heuristical, and possibly not very accurate. Please tell me if this is impossible, as I have no clue whether this is possible.

Comment: what is v? is it the number of the vertices? If so that algorithm hasn't been found yet. Have you checked this out? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem

Comment: Yes, I had a look at that. However, I have seen quite a few algorithms that do it in n^3 (heuristical). In other words, solving it with exactly the best thing is NP-complete, however, solving it with something which is slightly more inaccurate can be quite fast.